how do i observe changes made to kotlin's MutableList?
var questionPool: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
questionPool contains string ids. 
ids are added and removed throughout the application's lifecycle.
How can i execute a function foo whenever item(s) are added or removed from questionPool? 
Is there an observable for mutable lists?

Most implementations of MutableList are not observable, including the one created with mutableListOf(). We need to either implement our own mutable list or search for an existing library.
If implementing it by ourselves, we can delegate to a real list to make our code simpler and more flexible:
fun main() {
    val list = mutableListOf<String>().observe { println("changed: ${it.toList()}") }
    list += "hello" // changed: [hello]
    list += "world" // changed: [hello, world]
    list -= "hello" // changed: [world]
}

fun <T> MutableList<T>.observe(onChange: (MutableList<T>) -> Unit) = object : MutableList<T> by this {
    override fun add(element: T) = this@observe.add(element).also { onChange(this) }
    override fun remove(element: T) = this@observe.remove(element).also { onChange(this) }
}

Please note this is more like an example or proof of concept than the complete implementation. We still need to override more functions than above. Also, it would be probably useful to get information on what exactly changed in the list.

how about observing the size of the list? how would that work?@broot

In exactly the same way (?). I'm not sure what is the part that is tricky to you.

I suspect they were thinking that observing the size would be all that had to be done, as the size changes with every add or remove. I don't think it's possible to observe changes to the size property directly. Even if it were, the size wouldn't change with a call to set() but I assume they would want to observe that too.
